# I cannot resolve persistent merge conflicts between [develop] and [master] when using gitflow

Tags: git, merge, azure-devops

Environment:

- Azure DevOps
- Azure Repos (git)
- Git for Windows and/or built in git client with Visual Studio Code/Visual Studio Pro 2017/2019

We're using vanilla gitflow (https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), suitably modified for Azure DevOps:

1. Create feature branch from [develop]
2. Squash merge feature branch to [develop] via Pull Request
3. Cut pre-release branch [release/n.n.n] from head of [develop]
4. Squash merge [release/n.n.n] to [master] via Pull Request
5. Tag resulting merge commit for release to production

This repo has seen some history (pun intended) - it was migrated from github to Bitbucket to Azure Repos, and at one point the developers were forgetting to do squash merged PRs so the history got kind of messy.  Thus, I was not surprised when Step 4 above started showing merge conflicts between [release/n.n.n] and [master], despite there being no changes on [master] since the previous merge from the previous [release/] branch.  We have been resolving these by selecting "choose all incoming" in the Step 4 Pull Request.

What is flummoxing me is that I've been trying to stop this from happening, and nothing I do to get this repo to see [master] as strictly behind [develop] seems to work.  I have tried:

```
git checkout master
git checkout develop
git merge master
git push origin
```

```
git checkout master
git checkout develop
git merge --squash -X ours master
git push origin
```

```
git checkout master
git checkout develop
git merge --squash -s ours master
git push origin
```

All of these seem to work for a sprint or two, but then we'll get merge conflicts again.  The conflicts are not in the same lines, same files or same portions of the codebase.  They seem to be random.

I understand why `-X ours` probably didn't do what I wanted, but I really thought the resulting merge commit from `-s ours` would reliably become the new common ancestor of [develop] and [master].

What the devil am I missing?  Is it the squash merge type that's preventing this from working?

We have a dozen other repos using the same model and none of them have ever had this problem, so I'm assuming it's this repo's history that's corrupted and not the tooling or a developer misusing a git client.  [develop] and [master] are both protected by branch policies, so it's not possible for anyone to push to them without using a PR, and [master] shows no changes that aren't the result of a squash PR from a [release/] branch.

Comment: You cannot use squash merges to integrate two long-running branches without this happening.  You have to use a regular merge commit.

Comment: Well, we have a dozen other git repos in Azure Repos using this exact same model that don't have this problem, and squash merging in this fashion is actually Azure DevOps' recommended way of doing gitflow/releaseflow.  So clearly this problem isn't an inevitable result of squash merging.  So should I be using `git merge -s ours master && git push origin`?

Comment: I'm writing a FAQ entry on this for Git, and [GitHub documents this problem](https://docs.github.com/en/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-request-merges#squashing-and-merging-a-long-running-branch).  A regular `git merge` is almost certainly the right thing.